# Managed device - operating system manufacturer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune

I'm using MS Graph API to query information about devices enrolled in Intune. I need to find operating system name, version and manufacturer.

From the [managed devices endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/intune_devices_manageddevice), I am able to get the first two. However, OS manufacturer is not available.

The idea is to map OS name to a list of manufacturers. My question is - does anybody know if there is a finite list of OS names that Graph API returns for Intune enrolled devices?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no now.

You can create your own OS manufacturer list based on the OS name or just submit an feature request on [user voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/), so the product team maybe add the properties or docs in future.